# How to concatenate two ranges

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm trying to assign to a range of cells a value made up of two ranges, I want that `Range(Cells(i, 15), Cells(i, 25)).value` show the value of itself and `Range(Cells(k, 18), Cells(k, 28)).value`

```
 Range(Cells(i, 15), Cells(i, 25)).value = Range(Cells(k, 18), Cells(k, 28)).value & Range(Cells(i, 15), Cells(i, 25)).value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a loop like below: **(Tested)**

```
For j = 15 To 25

Cells(i, j).Value = Cells(k, j + 3).Value & Cells(i, j).Value

Next
```

Here `i` & `k` are the values already in your code.

Comment: Accept the Answer if it works :) @FrancescoBordignon

Answer (score 0):

You declare ranges in VBA with the **set** keyword.

```
Set myrange=range(cells)
```